Attach screenshot to pytest html report for fixture error
I have a fixture inside the test file which executes some required steps for each test. If the code in this fixture fails ( timeout for example ) the execution is marked as ERROR in the html report, using pytest-html, and no screenshot is taken.
I have written a decorator for the fixture to take a screenshot in case of exception and add it to extras, however, despite the screenshot part working fine, it is not added to the report.
Could the cause be that pytest-html simply doesn't allow adding screenshots to ERROR cases ?
Below is my code :
Fixture :
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
@screenshot_on_fixture_failure
def open_videochat_page(vi_rewrite_gui, request, extras):

global ident_id
vi_rewrite_gui.mobile_number = '+656181985165'
vi_rewrite_gui.open_userdata_page(shortname).fill_userdata_successfully()
vi_rewrite_gui.click_consent_btn()
vi_rewrite_gui.click_continue_btn()
vi_rewrite_gui.wait_for_channel_chooser()
vi_rewrite_gui.wait_for_page_to_load()
ident_id = vi_rewrite_gui.get_ident_id()
vi_rewrite_gui.select_web_channel().fill_web_channel_successfully().click_ready_continue()
vi_rewrite_gui.wait_for_cqc_success()

Decorator :
def screenshot_on_fixture_failure(fixture_func):
@wraps(fixture_func)
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # Execute the original fixture function
        return fixture_func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        extras = kwargs.get('extras')
        request = kwargs.get('request')
        driver_instance = kwargs.get('vi_rewrite_gui')
        screenshot_name = f"{request.node.name} - {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.png"
        # screenshot_path = os.path.join(SCREENSHOTS_PATH, screenshot_name)
        # driver_instance.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
        image = driver_instance.take_screenshot_base64()

        extras.append(pytest_html.extras.image(image, name=screenshot_name))

        print(f"Screenshot taken due to fixture error: {screenshot_name}")
        print(f"Error occurred in fixture: {str(e)}")
        # Re-raise the exception so the test fails
        raise e
return wrapper

html report

The function is get_screenshot_as_base64

yes, this is just another method on top     def take_screenshot_base64(self):
return self._driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
